# 2 sliding menu with different size

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I use this sliding menu as a library. I want to have 2 menu with different sizes. 
I have a problem : when i push the big one, another one will move with it

I change my main.java like this to have 2 different size menu in lef and right

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("Hello");
    // set the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // configure the SlidingMenu
    final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);


    DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = display.widthPixels;
    int menu_width = width - width / 3;
    if (menu_width < 100) {
        menu_width = 100;
    }
    menu.setBehindWidth(menu_width);  

    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    View view = G.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
    menu.setMenu(view);


    final SlidingMenu menu2 = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu2.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    menu2.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu2.setBehindWidth(menu_width / 2);   

    menu2.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu2.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    menu2.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu2.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    View view22 = G.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
    menu2.setMenu(view22);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using two sligingMenu instead try LEFT_RIGHT Mode for your `SlidingMenu` This class has method as setMode() 
[LEFT_RIGHT_ACTIVITY](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/example/LeftAndRightActivity.java)

Comment: because they should have different size

Answer (score 0):

you can use a code like this:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("Hello");
    // set the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // configure the SlidingMenu
    final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    /// get 1/3 screen width
    DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = display.widthPixels;
    int menu_width = width - width / 3;
    if (menu_width < 100) {
        menu_width = 100;
    }
    menu.setBehindWidth(menu_width);  // set the first sliding size

    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    View view = G.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
    menu.setMenu(view);


    final SlidingMenu menu2 = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu2.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    menu2.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu2.setBehindWidth(menu_width / 2);   // set the second sliding size half of first slidingه

    menu2.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu2.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    menu2.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu2.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    View view22 = G.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
    menu2.setMenu(view22);
```